# Deny access to a rails route if request does not originate from app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, ldap

I have a route in my application that returns results from an LDAP query. I'm using a privileged account for this as it needs to return information that a regular account can't access.

Is there a way to deny users access to this route if they're not using it via one of the application's views? What I'm trying to prevent is a someone reverse engineering it and building their own app to gain access to the PII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reliable way to say this request originated from this view vs. this request originated from (e.g.) the command line.

An HTTP URL request doesn't have a verifiable source of origination. There is a "referrer" HTTP header which is intended for saying where the previous request originated, but it is not for security and completely spoofable, and not even always included in the request.

Somehow you'll need to authenticate the request. Don't invent your own way. Use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or some other tested tool to build an authentication strategy, and figure out how to modify your application to work with existing conventions of HTTP request authentication (secure token, cookie based auth, etc.)